# Approximating an integral over Boundary of the Mandelbrot Set

Tags: integration, fractals, dimension-theory-analysis

It is a famous discovery by M Shishikura that the Hausdorff dimension of the Mandelbrot Set's boundary is 2.

I would like to computationally approximate the following integral:

$$I=\int_{\partial M} \frac{d\mathcal{H}^2(s)}{2s+1}.$$

The integral is in respect to $\mathcal{H}^2(s)$, which is the 2-dimensional Hausdorff measure.

Would I be able to approximate this with something akin to (where $B$ is some plane which contains $\partial M$):

$$I_p = \int_{B} \frac{1_{\partial M}}{2s+1} d\mathcal{H}^2_p(s).$$

If so, how could I approximate $1_{\partial M}$?

What would people suggest for computationally approximating this.

Comment: It is likely (but, as far as I know, not proved) that $\mathcal H^2(\partial M) = 0$.  If so, your integral $I$ is $0$.  What do you mean by $\mathcal H^2_p$ ?

Comment: +GEdgar By $\mathcal{H}^2_p$, I mean the Hausdorff measure approximated with "balls" of size $p$. Do you have any literature on how it is likely that the measure of the boundary is 0?

Comment: OK, a good way to approximate $\mathcal H^2$.  (Use balls of size **at most** $p$.) Of course in the plane $\mathbb C$, the measure $\mathcal H^2$ is (a constant times) $2$-dimentional Lebesgue measure.

Comment: See this [related article](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/MandelbrotSet.html) for the area of the Mandelbrot set.

Comment: +Tyma Gaidash The article you sent does not speak about the area of its boundary. Thank you, though.